# Swift Charts Candle chart does not correctly showing

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I am using th swift Charts library. I'm trying to show a candle chart but it does not correctly showing data.
After running it will be show just one item but if i will zoom in it will be show all items,

how immediately showing every item after running without needed to zoom ?

```
func setupCandleChart() {
   // candleChartView.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true // if enable this doesn't show anything
    setCandleDataCount(5, range: 30)
}

func setCandleDataCount(_ count: Int, range: UInt32) {
    let yVals1 = (0..<count).map { (i) -> CandleChartDataEntry in
        let mult = range + 1
        let val = Double(arc4random_uniform(40) + mult)
        let high = Double(arc4random_uniform(9) + 8)
        let low = Double(arc4random_uniform(9) + 8)
        let open = Double(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
        let close = Double(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
        let even = i % 2 == 0

        return CandleChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), shadowH: val + high, shadowL: val - low, open: even ? val + open : val - open, close: even ? val - close : val + close)
    }
    
    
    let set1 = CandleChartDataSet(entries: yVals1, label: "Data Set")
    let data = CandleChartData(dataSet: set1)
    candleChartView.data = data
}
```

[image]

if i will zoom:

[image]

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for me. Where are you calling setupCandleChart() method? Btw what is the usage of UISliders showed in your screenshots, could there be a side effect due to those?

Comment: @SamB do u use the latest version of these library (4.0.1) ? uislider for data generator, first slider its count, second slider its range

Comment: i ran example from github and its work same :(

Comment: @SamB the setupCandleChart() method i calling in xibSetup function. Do u use ios 15 ?

Comment: My setup is iOS 14.4 and Charts 3.6.0. I have added the chart programmatically and calling setupCandleChart() in loadView()

Comment: @SamB yeah, its 4.0.1 bug, download 4.0 version and works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)